# Building a simple search engine in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am a final year student. My project involves me building a simple search engine that can work like google.com. But I don't have an idea of how to go about this. Well based on my research I learnt that search engines work on search keyword with a webcrawlers locating page on search keywords. But how to put this to working code. I would appreciate useful study materials (url links).

Comment: Ohh pardon my use of English. I dont mean Google is Simple. I meant building a simple search Engine that can do a simple search micmicing google. @haim770

Comment: What are you planning to use as your back end?

Comment: What are the basic requirements of this search engine?

Comment: I intend using asp.net mvc4 framework. @Black Frog

Comment: The search engine is suppose to work like a medical dictionary. A user enters a keyword like malaria then the search engine gets information on malaria and displays back to the user. It suppose to something simple not really complex. The owl idea is entering a word and getting valid search feeds back to the user.  @haim770

Comment: I saw this while researching on google. It is called Google Client Library https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/libraries   I think this could do the job. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: When I meant in back-end, is the search result coming from Google or some a custom database?

Comment: Reading your question again do you want to build a web crawler?

Comment: yeah I want to build a web crawler. But when I saw the Google Client Library, I just felt I dont need to build a web crawler. I could leverage on google to get me the search result.